# Making React context available without top level wrapping

Tags: reactjs, react-context, primereact

I would like to use latest version of prime-react, but I see a trouble, that I will have.

Here is a snippet from their docs (https://primereact.org/installation/)

```
import { PrimeReactProvider } from 'primereact/api';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <PrimeReactProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </PrimeReactProvider>
    );
}
```

I understand these lines very well. The users should wrap their app with `PrimeReactProvider`, and all of the components down the tree will use this.

The problem I have is - our app is not written like this - the app is not "react" from the root. We only use react in some places. We just grab an element from the dom, and ReactDOM.render into it - we have **multiple** roots for the React.

What should I do, to make this context available in all of the places, where we use React?

One solution would be - anytime we ReactDOM.render - we wrap that thing in `<PrimeReactProvider>`. But that would create new instance of the context every time :(

Comment: You need one `<PrimeReactProvider>` that holds/manages the state. And you need to wrap your seperate react parts with a `<PrimeReactContext.Provider>` where you can forward/feed that state into. Basically bridge the gap between the seperate applications.

Comment: Does your use case mean you absolutely need shared state between the different react roots? Or is there some worry about duplicated side effects?

Comment: It can probably be done using https://github.com/pmndrs/its-fine?tab=readme-ov-file#usecontextbridge. Underlying impl is quite simple. It does mean you'd need to do the render calls for the individual roots after some dummy tree is loaded for the sake of being able to pull out the context values to provide back down via the raw underlying prime react context provider.

Comment: useContextBridge sounds like what I need

Comment: @adsy I added your answer as its the right one to use

Answer (score 0):

It can probably be done using`useContextBridge` https://github.com/pmndrs/its-fine?tab=readme-ov-file#usecontextbridge

Underlying implementation is quite simple. It does mean you'd need to do the render calls for the individual roots after some dummy tree is loaded for the sake of being able to pull out the context values to provide back down via the raw underlying prime react context provider.

Comment: But it still requires a single "root" where all of the components come from. As from their example - you can render them into other renderers, but they still have to be within the same root..